# How to encode special characters for a POST with Spring/Roo

Tags: java, url, encoding, post, special-characters

I'm using Spring/Roo for an app server, and need to be able to post some special characters. Specifically, characters like the Yen symbol, or Euro symbol. When I receive these characters on my server, and display them in console, they appear as "?". How can they be properly encoded and received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of possible failure points here.

First, I'd check to see if the console supports the characters in question:

- if the default encoding used by the JVM does not support the characters, they will be turned into question marks by `System.out`
- if the console font does not support the characters, they will not be rendered properly
- if the console is decoding the bytes using a different encoding to the one `System.out` is encoding them to, the characters will not display correctly

Instead of trying to print characters as literal, cast to `int` and print the hex value - then check the value against the [Unicode charts](http://unicode.org/charts/).

Lossy or incorrect conversions can also happen between the browser and the server. Ideally, the server should use UTF-8 for encoding and decoding. If the encoding used by the browser when it encodes the data does not support the characters, they will be lossily encoded; the browser usually picks an encoding based on the encoding sent by the server for the GET request (or more rarely from a [form attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset)). Inspect the `Accept-Charset` [header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) being sent with your data (you can do this with something like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)). I don't know anything about Roo, but there's bound to be some mechanism to configure encodings.

Answer (score 6):

Try configuring `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties` to this :

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://[YOUR_DB_SERVER]:3306/[YOUR_DB_NAME]?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```