# spring-roo maven project does not support special characters

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, encoding, spring-roo

I'm using Spring/Roo with maven for an app server, and need to be able to post some special characters, like "ñ á é". When I print these characters on my server, and display them in console, they appear as "?", like this

```
  System.out.print("ñ á é");
  console print -> ? ? ?
```

How can they be properly encoded, i have another project without maven and spring-roo, using the same JVM, and i don't have this issues

hope someone can help thx in advance

Comment: The console printing them as "?" doesn't prove that they are encoded wrong, it just shows that the problem might be the console encoding.

Comment: always show '???', if i return the string using ajax call, show the same '? ? ?', am really lost, don't know if is a maven configuration, or spring roo configuration...

Comment: i found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609199/how-to-encode-special-characters-for-a-post-with-spring-roo) but how can i configure the encodings

Comment: Is you IDE correctly configured to use UTF-8 as well? If you are on windows the default is cp1252 and NOT UTF-8 ?

Comment: Already check and the configuration is set in UTF-8, this problem only happen with the project made with spring-roo, so i guess something is missing in the configuration that roo does in the project, a dependency missing in the pom.xml ... don't know

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in Roo the following parts is somewhere found in the pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```